# How to access containerized asp.net core (docker EE windows container) from outside Windows Server 2016 VM host?

Tags: docker, networking, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-container

I am new to docker and windows container world. I am creating a sample application using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with SQL Server 2016 Backend. I am able to run the application successfully directly on Windows Server 2016 VM. Next I containerized it using Docker EE Windows Container. I started the container and able to browse the application from Windows Server 2016 VM host.

This is how I build and started the container, please assume I have created the .dockerfile with appropriate values.

```
docker build -t testapi .

docker run -d --name testapi_app --rm -it -p 8000:80 testapi
```

When I run

```
docker network ls
```

I get

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
38c9f8e165bf        nat                 nat                 local
f97c096a0ef6        none                null                local
```

When I run following command (02f4 is the container id first 4 characters)

```
docker exec 02f4 ipconfig
```

I can see the IPv4 address as 172.25.5.26

I am able to browse the application from host windows server 2016 VM using http://172.25.5.26/api/values

And I am getting the response back.

I will really appreciate if anyone can point me to some resources that can help me with how to make the application hosted with windows container using docker EE on a windows server 2016 VM host to be browsable from outside the host VM.

I feel like I may have to change some network options, but not exactly sure what is that I must change.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this question would be better asked (and answered) on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) as it is more configuration and setup of a hosted environment rather than direct coding related.

Comment: Good suggestion, Thank you. I will post the question there.

Comment: Do you understand what `-p 8000:80` is doing? Why did you think you needed the container IP?

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you. I was just following the tutorial and didn't pay attention to -p 8000:80, after you asked the question, then I realized that   the -p is exposing port 80 of container to 8000 port on host. I am now able to access the application. Instead of trying to browse http://172.25.5.26/api/values, I had to access it from outside using http://<hostip>:8000/api/values

Comment: Yup, that's how to do it ;)